# Diferencia entre subprocess.run y subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, python-3.x, proceso

Tengo una duda con la librería `subprocess`:

¿Cual es la diferencia entre usar `subprocess.run()` y `Popen()` y en que circunstancias se debe utilizar cada una?

Comment: Por favor realiza una pregunta por publicación, si tienes otra duda crea otra publicación. Ambas preguntas son independientes. Lee [ask].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El núcleo del módulo `subprocess` es [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), por su parte [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) fue agregado  en Python 3.5 y es básicamente un **wrapper/envoltura sobre `subprocess.Popen`** y que se creó para integrar y unificar varia funciones antiguas como `subprocess.call`. Básicamente permite ejecutar un comando en un subproceso y **esperar** hasta que termine.

La palabra clave es "esperar", `run` **bloquea** el proceso principal hasta que el comando ejecutado en el proceso hijo termina mientras que con `subprocess.Popen` puedes continuar paralelamente haciendo cosas en el proceso padre mientras tanto, llamando a `subprocess.communicate` para pasar o recibir datos de los subprocesos caundo se desee.

Como ya se ha comentado, `subprocess.run` solo facilita el uso, por debajo se llama a `subprocess.Popen` y se hace uso de `subprocess.comunicate`. De hecho, todos los argumentos son pasados directamente al constructor de `Popen` menos tres:

- `timeout`: se pasa a `Popen.communicate` generando una excepción `TimeoutExpired` si el el proceso no retorna antes del mismo. No obstante, ha diferencia de lo que ocurre con `Popen.comunicate` crudo, previamente a lanzar la excepción se mandan instrucciones para matar al proceso hijo y se espera.
- `input`: también se pasa a `Popen.communicate`. Como advertencia, cuando se usa este argumento internamente Popen asocia stdin con una tubería (`stdin = subprocess.PIPE`) por lo que no debe ser usada conjuntamente con el argumento `stdin`.
- `check`:  si el proceso sale con un código de salida distinto de cero, se generará una excepción [`CalledProcessError`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CalledProcessError).

Por otro lado, `subproccess.run` **retorna un objeto [`subprocess.CompletedProcess`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess)** representando el resultado de un proceso terminado:

- `subprocess.CompletedProcess.args`: son los argumentos usados para lanzar el proceso, en relación directa con el objeto pasado al argumento `args` de `subprocess.run`.
- `subprocess.CompletedProcess.returncode`: es simplemente el estado de salida del proceso. Típicamente 0 indica que el proceso se ejecutó correctamente, aunque lógicamente es algo que es definido por el propio proceso.
- `subprocess.CompletedProcess.stdout`: captura la salida estándar del subproceso o `None` si no se ha capturado. Es una cadena de bytes o una cadena de texto (`str`) si  si se pasó `True` al argumento `universal_newlines=True`de `subprocess.run`. Para poder capturar la salida es necesario redirigirla mediante una tubería al llamar a `subprocess.run` mediante `stdout=subperocess.PIPE`
- `subprocess.CompletedProcess.stderr`: exactamente lo mismo que el atributo anterior, solo que para `stderr`.
- `subprocess.CompletedProcess.check_returncode()`: igual que cuando se define `check` como `True` en el constructor de `subprocess.run`, este método  cuando es llamado lanza una excepción `CalledProcessError` si el código de retorno del subproceso no es cero.

Llegados a este punto, la segunda duda que  planteas sobre cuando usar uno u otro ya está respondida. Lo que te tienes que preguntar es **¿Quiero esperar a que el comando se ejecute y termine antes de continuar la ejecución en el proceso padre?**. Si es así usa `subprocess.run`. Obviamente puedes conseguir lo mismo con `subprocess.Popen` + `comunicate()`, pero requiere más código y trabajo (de ahí la justificación de la existencia de `run`).

Un ejemplo muy simplificado, imaginemos que tenemos el siguiente script Python en un sistema *nix que vamos a ejecutar como un subproceso:

```
import select
import sys
import time


for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(1)
    if select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0.0)[0]:
        if sys.stdin.read() == "salir":
            break
print(f"Se ha esperado {i} segundos")
```

como ejemplo, no hace nada, simplemente el proceso tarda unos 10 segundos en terminar pero podemos pararlo en cualquier momento si le mandamos "salir" vía stdin.

Si lanzamos el proceso vía **subprocess.run**, nuestro proceso padre se bloquea los 10 segundos que el hijo tarda en retornar sin más:

```
import subprocess


process = subprocess.run(args=["python", "dropdownlist.py"],
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                           encoding='utf8'
                           )
print(process.stdout)
```

> Se ha esperado 10 segundos

Una vez lanzado el subproceso, nuestro procesio principal se bloquea y solo continua (ejecutando  `print(process.stdout)`) cuando el subproceso termina.

En cambio usando `subprocess.Popen` podemos hacer otras cosas mientras el proceso se ejecuta y eventualemente comunicarnos en algún momento con el para detenerlo:

```
import subprocess
import time


process = subprocess.Popen(args=["python", "dropdownlist.py"],
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                           encoding='utf8'
                           )

time.sleep(5) # hacemos cualquier cosa mientra tanto
out, _ = process.communicate("salir")
print(out)
```

> Se ha esperado 5 segundos

Imagina que tienes un programa CLI que reproduce archivos de audio y que a la vez que reproduce retorna cierta información vía salida estándar como el progreso y además permite enviarle comandos para pausar, reanudar, etc. Si quieres ejecutar dicho programa desde un script en Python, podrías plantearte dos posibilidades. Si solo quieres reproducir de principio a fin un archivo y que mientras tanto tu script Python solo espere y no haga nada, `subprocess.run` sería tu elección más simple. Si quieres poder parar, reanudar, etc la reproduccion a la vez que usar la información que el reproductor envía `subprocess.Popen` + `comunicate` (para enviar los comandos y recibir la información que el reproductor envía vía stdout) es la opción adecuada.

Siguiendo la misma lógica, si quieres lanzar varios comandos vía subproceso destinados a correr paralelamente, debes usar `subprocess.Popen` ya que `subprocess.run` los ejecutaría en serie.